# How can I know the dependencies of a certain package?

Tags: dependencies

Is it possible to list out the dependencies of a software/package in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
apt-cache depends package
```

**apt-cache depends** shows a listing of each dependency a package has and all the possible other packages that can fulfill that dependency. (see: man apt-cache)

Answer (score 3):

**Install apt-rdepends in Ubuntu**

```
sudo aptitude install apt-rdepends
```

This will install all the required packages.

**Using apt-rdepends**

**apt-rdepends Syntax**

```
sudo apt-rdepends [options] [pkgs ...]
```

**apt-rdepends Examples**

```
sudo apt-rdepends bash
```

**Output looks like below**

```
Reading package lists… Done
Building dependency tree… Done
bash
Depends: base-files (>= 2.1.12)
Depends: debianutils (>= 2.15)
PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.3.6-6)
PreDepends: libncurses5 (>= 5.4-5)
base-files
Depends: awk
Depends: base-passwd (>= 2.0.3.4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Type `dpkg-deb -I file` in a terminal. Note "file" represents the package whose dependencies you want to see.

Comment: When I run "dpkg-deb -I totem", it says no such file found. Hence, I don't think this is an apt answer.